# Generating an EF Core migration script errors for missing .deps.json file

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines, entity-framework-migrations

I am adding Entity Framework Core migrations to my Azure pipeline. After build and test I am attempting to create the migration script

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Install EF tool'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      custom: 'tool'
      arguments: 'install dotnet-ef --global --version 7.0.5'
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Generate EF SQL Script'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      custom: 'ef'
      configuration: 'release'
      arguments: 'migrations script --no-build --verbose --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\"HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj" --output $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\script.sql  --idempotent'
```

The error comes in the task `Generate EF SQL Script`.  It appears to look for the file in Debug? `The specified deps.json [C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\bin\Debug\net6.0\HR Taxonomy Change Management.deps.json] does not exist`.  The does exist in the Release folder.  I hope I'm not supposed to copy the file from Release to Debug?  That sounds "hacky".

```
Starting: Generate EF SQL Script (windows_build_container)
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.235.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ef migrations script --no-build --verbose --project "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj" --output C:\__w\1\s\script.sql --idempotent
Using project 'C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj'.
Using startup project 'C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj'.
Writing 'C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\obj\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpD626.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj"
Writing 'C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\obj\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDD0D.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj"
dotnet exec --depsfile "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\bin\Debug\net6.0\HR Taxonomy Change Management.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages" C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\7.0.5\dotnet-ef\7.0.5\tools\net6.0\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations script --output C:\__w\1\s\script.sql --idempotent --assembly "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\bin\Debug\net6.0\HR Taxonomy Change Management.dll" --project "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj" --startup-assembly "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\bin\Debug\net6.0\HR Taxonomy Change Management.dll" --startup-project "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj" --project-dir "C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\\" --root-namespace HR_Taxonomy_Change_Management --language C# --framework net6.0 --nullable --working-dir C:\__w\1\s --verbose
The specified deps.json [C:\__w\1\s\HR Taxonomy Change Management\bin\Debug\net6.0\HR Taxonomy Change Management.deps.json] does not exist
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 2147516545
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ]
Finishing: Generate EF SQL Script (windows_build_container)
```

**Update:**
@AlvinZhao asked about the build task and it is set to Release:

```
 - task: MSBuild@1
            displayName: 'ChgMgmt Build'
            inputs:
              solution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\HR Taxonomy Change Management\*.csproj'
              msbuildLocationMethod: 'version'
              msbuildVersion: 'latest'
              platform: 'x64'
              configuration: 'release'
              msbuildArguments: '/v:n /nr:false /flp1:Verbosity=d;LogFile=$(OUTPUTROOT)\logs\msbuild_x64_release.log;Encoding=UTF-8 /flp2:logfile=$(OUTPUTROOT)\logs\msbuild_x64_release.err;errorsonly /bl:$(OUTPUTROOT)\logs\msbuild_x64_release.binlog'
              clean: true
              maximumCpuCount: true
              logProjectEvents: true
              createLogFile: true
```

Comment: May I know if there was a previous task that built your project `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\"HR Taxonomy Change Management\HR Taxonomy Change Management.csproj"` and whether the `dotnet build` command was followed by an option of `--configuration Release` or `--configuration Debug`?

Comment: @AlvinZhao I added the build task to my question.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @USMC6072, Thanks for your taking time to share the solution of removing the  `--no-build` argument in the `Generate EF SQL Script` task, which may help other community members encountering similar issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be as simple as removing the  `--no-build` argument in the `Generate EF SQL Script` task